# bootstrap 5 multiple nested offcanvas

Tags: bootstrap-5

I want to have a multiple nested offcanvas for Bootstrap 5.
When I click a button, the first offcanvas should be opened and then click another button which is on the first offcanvas, the second offcanvas should be opened over the first offcanvas and the first offcanvas should not be closed.
I will make second one smaller and so the first one still be shown.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#offcanvasExample" role="button" aria-controls="offcanvasExample">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#offcanvasExample2" role="button" aria-controls="offcanvasExample">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#offcanvasExample3" role="button" aria-controls="offcanvasExample">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#offcanvasExample4" role="button" aria-controls="offcanvasExample">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </a>

        <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasExample" aria-labelledby="offcanvasExampleLabel">
            <div class="offcanvas-header">
                <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasExampleLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="offcanvas-body">
                <div>
                    Some text as placeholder. In real life you can have the elements you have chosen. Like, text, images, lists, etc.
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown mt-3">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#offcanvasExample6" role="button" aria-controls="offcanvasExample">
                        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasExample6" aria-labelledby="offcanvasExampleLabel">
            <div class="offcanvas-header">
                <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasExampleLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="offcanvas-body">
                <div>
                    Some text as placeholder. In real life you can have the elements you have chosen. Like, text, images, lists, etc.
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown mt-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
                  Dropdown button
                </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/offcanvas/)...

> "Similar to modals, only one offcanvas can be shown at a time."

Answer (score 0):

By default, as written above, offcanvas doesn't support multipe. But this is not a big problem to solve.

First, you need to set the z-index properly. If your 5 offcanvas always appear in the same order, this can be done statically via CSS/style-attribute. If the order can change dynamically, you need to set the z-index via JS. Use the show.bs.offcanvas event to trigger your script.

The second problem is all the actions that apply to the background. Like darken, etc.
Solution 1: Disable them all via bootstrap options. (especial backdrop=false)
Solution 2: only the first on should apply actions to the backdrop (like darken), the rest should not.
Solution 3: Calculate this dynamic also when offcanvas is open.
Solution 4: (for darkening the background)
The darkening is done by a div with the class offcanvas-backdrop. Only one should have a "show" class.

But better is, not to open multipe offcanvas, so I did write a script, wich close all other offcanvas, store them on a stack an reactivate them if the newest offcanvas ist closed.
But there are to bugs in bootstrap. It activates and deactivates **all** backdrops on show/hide offcanvas. Therefore the script fix that also. If you use it, you can open as many offcanvas, as you like.

```
global_offcanvas_stack = [];
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.offcanvas').each(function(  ) {
      if(global_offcanvas_debug) console.info( "bootstrap_multi_offcanvas: Attach to",$(this).attr('id') );
      this.addEventListener('shown.bs.offcanvas',closeOtherOffCanvas);
      this.addEventListener('hide.bs.offcanvas',openLastOffCanvas);
    });
});

function closeOtherOffCanvas(event) {
   id = $(event.target).attr('id');

   $('.offcanvas').each(function(){ // gehe alle offcanvas durch

      if ($(this).hasClass('show') && $(this).attr('id') != id) {  
         global_offcanvas_stack.push($(this).attr('id'));
         $(this).hide();
      }
   });
   // fix the Bugs, that activate all backdrops 
   backdrop = $(".offcanvas-backdrop.fade.show");    
   if (backdrop.length> 1) {
      backdrop.each( function(i) { /
         if (i != 0) { 
            $(this).removeClass("show");
         }
         
      });
   }
};

function openLastOffCanvas(event) {
   if (global_offcanvas_stack.length> 0 ) {
      id =global_offcanvas_stack.pop();
      $('#'+id).show();
      // fix the Bugs, Bootstrap hide all backdrops
      if ($(".offcanvas-backdrop.fade.show").length == 0) { // no Backdrop?
         $(".offcanvas-backdrop.fade:not(.show)").first().addClass("show"); 
      }
   }
};
```

That works not with dynamic creates offcanvas. There you have to bind the two handlers by yourself.